# What's up with the late answers queue?

Tags: bug, review-queue

It looks like we currently have 4400+ late answers awaiting review:

[image: screenshot]

Obviously that's not possible, so what's up with that review queue?

Looks like a server-side issue, however using Google Chrome 45.0.2454.93.

Comment: Seems to be SE-wide. Also happening on [unix.se] with 600+ late answers.

Comment: @muru Nice catch, checking out Meta.SE now, if it hasn't been reported yet posting it there as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

30 minutes ago, [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/270345) was tagged [status-completed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/status-completed):

> I would like to raise the bar for **late answers** to enter the **Late
>   Answers Review Queue** to 50 rep, which is the threshold after which
>   users gain the ability **to comment**. Here are some answers that were
>   posted by users with between 10 to 50 rep (yes, there's a little
>   selection bias to be sure. I suspect most/all of these will be 10k
>   links only by the time you're reading this. Note, all of these are
>   from the **last 5 hours.**

Quoting [the proposal by SE employee Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/270345):

> Raising the bar to 100 would require changing two variables at once.
>   Since that would make it harder to evaluate each individual change,
>   I'd like to try raising the reputation for getting enqueued to the
>   Late Answer reviews to 50 and reconsider upping it to 100 at some
>   point in the future.

That seems to be it.

It's definitely a bug, though. From [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue#comment866393_267080):

> Just to note, the answers should not be older than a month and the
>   current spike *should* be temporary. –  Jon Ericson♦

---

*Sigh*:

> @muru: I'm sorry about that. Thank goodness I didn't raise the limit
>   to 100. As a reminder, it's easier to clear a task from this queue
>   than many others. A single review dequeues. –  Jon Ericson♦
>
> @Sven: Reverting won't help, I'm afraid. The damage has been done. I
>   have gone over to pitch in on Server Fault as an act of penitence. – 
>   Jon Ericson♦

---

### Let's get cracking, folks.

Comment: Yes, just went through the post as well. Hopefully that's actually temporary. I mean, *4.4K+* late answers. We have the close votes queue already. :)

Comment: @kos we seem to be [leading the pack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267081/270345).

Comment: And by quite a big bit. I was curious to see what's going on on Stack Overflow, but well, not enough rep over there.

Comment: @kos the discussion post said 1300. Not much.

Comment: Ah right, nevermind, I just went through the numbers and didn't think. Well honestly I would have expected more, good for them seeing your latest edit: what? So we have to fix that? :'(

Comment: @kos Think of it this way: We're gonna get the elusive fifth Steward badge. :)

Comment: Hah, that at least! Well, heading to the late answers queue (where I guess I'll spend some time in the next days), with a tear dropping down my cheeck :(

Comment: I don't know about you, but this mistake seems to have some advantages. Those old bad post lingering on the site since 2011 can be cleaned up. If only that happened on the Low Quality queue, then probably lots of unanswered bad questions would have been removed :P

Comment: @Dan problem is, 3x or 4x upvoted and even accepted answers are showing up frequently enough. :( Too much signal (which is ironic since we're looking to filter out noise)