# Late answers queue dramatically increased in size

Tags: discussion, support, review-queue, late-answers

I understand [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) this is happening, however there aren't that many people working on these queues, and this will definitely put them off if it never shrinks. So will there be any way implemented to make the shrinking of this queue faster, such as a reviewing event where the 20 per day limit is disabled or at least lowered (as suggested in [@ByteCommander's comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14472/late-answers-queue-dramatically-increased-in-size?noredirect=1#comment25389_14472))?

Comment: +1 to signalize protest against this overnight action from the Meta.SE developers. I would love the limit to be lowered again, maybe to 30 as a compromise. You should however edit your question and instead of asking whether it will ever shrink (which depends on us - the reviewing community), you could rather ask whether there will be anything to work on that queue faster, like a reviewing event, disabling the 20 reviews per day limit for a while or a decrease of the limit again....

Comment: @ByteCommander: Ok, thank you for your feedback, I have updated my question. :)

Comment: Stop asking questions about it!  If the queue is larger then 1000, you can review 40 items per day: get to it!  **;-)** (I am and finding lots of excrement!)

Comment: @Fabby 40 is still not much compared to almost 4000 items in the to-do list. That are 100 reviewer-days. And now tell me how many users really take advantage of all of their 40 review items?

Comment: @ByteCommander I do!  You should too!  **>:-)**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing to clarify is that the overnight increase happened because all the old answers that matched the new criteria were added to the queue. Once reviewed, they will be ineligible to reenter the queue. So this won't be a perpetual problem; it's just a temporary increase that will dissipate as people complete review tasks.

Second, as long as there are more than a thousand tasks in the queue, the per-day limit is raised to 40. [You can see](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/stats) several people have already taken advantage of that.

Third, Late Answers can be quickly dismissed by a single user taking an action that can be as simple as upvoting a comment. (Please don't just do the easiest action: try to review honestly.)

Finally, the queue is often empty because there aren't so many late answers in a typical day. I'm convinced that there are many people on most sites who would like to review more late answers, but can't because the queue is normally empty. People lucky enough to spot them get to late answers quickly. When the queue is filled, there are people willing to jump into the fray. We should see the number of completed reviews scale with the number of available reviews. Certainly that's been the case so far:

[image: Late Answers completed]

It wasn't my intention to cause this disruption. But now that I have, I expect we'll be able to learn quite a bit about how reviews impact other parts of the site.

Comment: This is disappointing. I have already mentioned that a lot of posts will be flagged, there will also be a lot of edits suggested. By refusing to acknowledge the effects on vlq and edit review queues, you show incompetence, nothing else.

Comment: @muru: Oh, I acknowledge incompetence. Several times, I believe. The trick now that I've caused this disruption is to learn from it so that I will be a little better at my job next time. There are certainly going to be pressures on other parts of the system (don't forget people will likely run out of votes more quickly too). I'm not "refusing to acknowledge" as much as looking at different things. There is a lot to look at.

Comment: there is a lot to look at, true. But when you enumerate points and, say, "finally" and none of those points relate to the effects on other queues, it does look like you're refusing to acknowledge them.

Comment: @muru: There are currently 40 tasks in the Low Quality queue and none in the Suggested Edit. That's  compared to 3535 in the Late Answer queue.  (For the sake of completeness: 514 Close Vote and 2 First Posts tasks. No Reopen Votes.) I guess I'm not sure what I'm supposed to say about the other queues.

Comment: And yet I exhausted my quota of edit and vlq reviews early on today. So clearly there is a gap here. That there is currently (late into the day) none, doesn't say much about when everyone's limits are fresh at the start of the UTC day.

Comment: @muru: Ah. I see where you are coming from now. I'm far more stymied by the vote quota, but I can see how that would be frustrating in addition. However, I take considerable comfort in my first paragraph which reminds me that this will all be over in a few weeks. The steady state will be a slightly higher level of late answers which will have a quite marginal influence on other queues. I also hope people are taking advantage of this opportunity to clear out (old) low quality answers and edit ones that need improvement. I hope there are a few hidden gems that deserve an upvote or two as well.

Comment: Thanks for reminding of upvotes. I've been letting "good enough" posts by with "no action needed", maybe I should upvote some.

Comment: Thanks for being honest and admitting a mistake.  And now for a bit of wisdom: "Errare humanum est, sed perseverare diabolicom est".  **;-)**
I'll be back tomorrow to do some more reviewing as I ran out of [all kinds of votes today](http://i.stack.imgur.com/40DbZ.png).  Is there an easy way (without risk!) of doubling votes for all users until this gets cleaned up?

Answer (score 1):

The threshold, being the queue currently bigger than 1K, "has been increased" to 40 already; this is clear just by looking at the [daily late answers review stats](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/stats), however: [How come my vote cap for "First Posts" is lower than others?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152200/how-come-my-vote-cap-for-first-posts-is-lower-than-others);

Also, it will shrink: since when [I asked about why the queue increased](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14469/whats-up-with-the-late-answers-queue) yesterday, it shrunk by ~800 questions already;

Assuming the current rate, it should be empty in about 4.5 days.