# Can we have the review audits suspended from the Late Answers queue?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, late-answers

When there is a lot of work to be done getting <strike>2</strike> <strike>3</strike>  <strike>4</strike>  <strike>5</strike> 6 audits in <strike>18</strike> <strike>24</strike> <strike>31</strike> <strike>40</strike> 48 items is more than distracting - one of them actually came **three times** (I know, its pure random, but still I'd rather have it turned off for the time being)

Comment: Ah! Bliss! **;-)** We can always dream...  But you can try your luck on [meta.se]...

Comment: @Fabby doubtful. I think only three sites still have > 1k late answers.

Comment: @Fabby, well I never, got burnt there twice :-)

Comment: So when we need it most turn it off? If there were abusive reviewers before the temptation of thousands of reviews will bring many more. Bad audit days are going to happen and I don't think there is any way around that.

Comment: @Seth, there is much truth in what you say - alas.

Comment: @Seth: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby - do you have that last comment set as a template or something :) That queue is annoying anyway, some of the answers may be rubbish but many a time the questions are pure rubbish

Comment: @Wilf: yes of course I do: I've got a bunch of them.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it seems urgent to take care of these review tasks and therefore worth removing obstacles that hamper your efforts. As the person who caused the flood, my initial impulse was to level the path. But upon further reflection, I couldn't think of any reason to suspend audits. While reviewing *really old* late answers is suboptimal, I still think it's important to upvote hidden gems and correct obvious problems. So we still want people to consider their review actions with the same care as normal.

In addition, this is a rare opportunity for user to gain experience with late answer reviews. Repetition is the key to [learning a skill](https://principlesoflearning.wordpress.com/dissertation/chapter-4-results/themes-identified/repetition/) yet the Late Answers queue is typically empty after completing one review. We should not waterdown this unique opportunity by removing the ordinary audits.

Finally, one the initial shock wore off, I realized this queue was particularly easy to [burn down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) since a single review can dequeue an answer. In fact, the queue has dropped from [4.4k](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14469/whats-up-with-the-late-answers-queue) to 700 tasks in just over a week without removing audits. This was a singular opportunity for earning the elusive [Late Answer Reviewer badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/94/reviewer) (and [Steward](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/126/steward)), which, I hope, softens the blow.

Comment: No worries, Seth already convinced me that this would be the _wrong thing to do_™ - but you have to admit that every 8th review being an audit gets strenuous :-)